# Sticky Navbar Appears in Middle of Full-Page Screenshot Using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer to take a full-page screenshot of a website, but I'm encountering an issue where the sticky navbar, which should remain at the top, is appearing in the middle of the screenshot, outside of its usual position. I've tried referencing the specific navbar class to attempt to keep it in place but with no luck. My best version to date is where I just hide the navbar all together and it did not display in the output however ideally it would.

**code snippet:**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function takeFullPageScreenshot(url, outputPath) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080, deviceScaleFactor: 2 });
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

    await incrementalScroll(page);

    await hideNavbar(page);

    await page.screenshot({ path: outputPath, fullPage: true });

    await browser.close();
    console.log(`Screenshot saved to ${outputPath}`);
}

async function incrementalScroll(page) {
    const scrollStep = 500;
    const scrollDelay = 100; 

    await page.evaluate(async (step, delay) => {
        const getScrollHeight = () => document.body.scrollHeight;
        let currentPosition = 0;

        while (currentPosition < getScrollHeight()) {
            window.scrollBy(0, step);
            currentPosition += step;
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));
        }
    }, scrollStep, scrollDelay);

    await page.evaluate(() => window.scrollTo(0, 0));
}

async function hideNavbar(page) {
    await page.evaluate(() => {
        const navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar.fixed-top');
        if (navbar) {
            navbar.style.display = 'none'; 
        }
    });
}

takeFullPageScreenshot('https://hunter-ed.com', 'hq-screenshot.png');
```

**Current Output:**
The sticky navbar is visible in the middle of the page in the screenshot.
[image: current]

**Desired Output:**
The full-page screenshot without the sticky navbar appearing in the middle. The navbar should be at the top.

[image: desired]

How can I fix this issue?